Odoo 17 bypass invoice check on sales_sub failed
When you try to close a sub without an invoice linked to it, Odoo raises a validation error.
I'm trying to bypass the invoice check by commenting on all the relevant lines. But Odoo still performs the check.
Here is my code:
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import _,models, fields
# from odoo.exceptions import ValidationError


class SaleSubscriptionCloseReasonWizard(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = "sale.subscription.close.reason.wizard"

    close_reason_id = fields.Many2one("sale.order.close.reason", string="Close Reason", required=True)

    def new(self, values=None, origin=None, ref=None):
        # sale_order = self.env['sale.order'].browse(self.env.context.get('active_id'))
        # invoice_free = not any(
        #     state in ['draft', 'posted'] for state in sale_order.order_line.invoice_lines.move_id.mapped('state'))
        # if invoice_free:
        #     raise ValidationError(_("""You can not churn a contract that has not been invoiced. Please cancel the contract instead."""))
        return super().new(values=values, origin=origin, ref=ref)

    def set_close(self):
        self.ensure_one()
        sale_order = self.env['sale.order'].browse(self.env.context.get('active_id'))
        sale_order.close_reason_id = self.close_reason_id
        sale_order.set_close(close_reason_id=self.close_reason_id.id)

Either the inheritance  is not working, commenting out/deleting the relevant lines is not the way to do or the Odoo performs the check somewhere else.
I tried commenting out or deleting the lines. I wish to be able to close (not cancel) subs without invoices.
